# Is it possible to install GnuPG without admin rights on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, gnupg

I'd like to install [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/download/) on my Windows 7 workstation, but since it's an office workstation, I don't have administrator rights. Is it still possible to install it without admin rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get a portable version from somewhere. I would search PortableApps first but any other choice of distribution will work.

Note that you will lost couple features require system integration (admin installation) because neither your OS or other programs will see you have GNUPG installed when running portable, these features include its right-click menu items, or inter-program actions, etc.